# When using string vector initializer, I get a runtime error "terminate called after throwing instance of `std::length_error`"

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following code in `test.cpp`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>

class A {
public:
  static const std::vector<std::string> foo;
};
const std::vector<std::string> A::foo {{"bar", "baz"}};

int main() {}
```

It compiles, but when I run it, I get the following error:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::length_error'
  what():  basic_string::_S_create
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Why am I getting this error?

*Hopefully irrelevant: I'm using g++ 4.8.2, with `-std=c++11`.*

*Aside: I purposely initialized `foo` outside the class. If I do it inside the class, the compiler tells me that an out-of-class initialization is required (which is ridiculous, imo).*

Comment: you should post the actual code, that code does not even compile (I didn't downvote, btw)

Comment: Yes, it does compile. I had an issue where I forgot `A::foo`, and I edited the question. But it still compiled before that edit. I copied and pasted the actual code. And the question still stands, btw. Even with `A::foo` I get the same error.

Comment: Don't use double braces.

Comment: @T.C. - wow! What a ridiculous issue. Why doesn't the compiler catch that?

Comment: Seems inefficient for the compiler to defer it to runtime, it should recognize `std::string` as a special case, or something.

Comment: You can reduce your problem to `int main() { std::string s = {"bar", "baz"} ; }`

Comment: Uniform initialization: swap one bunch of problems for another bunch of problems :)

Answer (score 8):

Fact #1: a string literal, which is `const char [N]`, can decay into a `const char *`.

Fact #2: `std::string` has a constructor taking two iterators.

Fact #3: A pointer is an iterator.

Result:
In

```
const std::vector<std::string> A::foo {{"bar", "baz"}};
```

the initializer can be parsed in two different ways:

1. `{"bar", "baz"}` is the initializer for a single `std::string` using the two-iterator constructor. Outer braces create an `initializer_list<std::string>`
2. `"bar"` and `"baz"` are initializers for two `std::string`s. `{"bar", "baz"}` creates an `initializer_list<std::string>`. Outer braces are redundant.

You want #2. The standard says the compiler must pick #1. Havoc ensues.

Comment: Classic. You want something. Computer says `no`. Havoc ensues :-)

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in the vector initialization:

```
const std::vector<std::string> A::foo {{"bar", "baz"}};
```

You cannot use double brackets, I don't even know what constructor is calling there (I guess is trying to create a vector from a char* array that doesn't end)...

This one should work (note I removed some brackets):

```
const std::vector<std::string> A::foo {"bar", "baz"};
```